# Did Texas ban tampons and diabetes supplies from the Senate Chamber while allowing guns?

Tags: united-states, politics

From an [article on Forward Progressives](http://www.forwardprogressives.com/texas-officially-loses-it-bans-tampons-and-diabetic-supplies-from-senate-chamber-guns-ok/):

> The Texas Department of Public Safety forced women to hand over their
>   tampons and pads before entering the Senate chamber today. Not only
>   that, but they were also forcing diabetics to hand over sugar packets
>   and other diabetes supplies which are lifelines when dealing with low
>   blood glucose levels.

The article also claims that guns were allowed in the Senate Chambers:

> And the kicker — those with concealed handgun licenses who wanted to
>   enter the Senate chamber were not only allowed to keep their handguns,
>   but they were allowed to bypass the long lines and enter through a
>   “special” CHL (concealed handgun license) line.

The whole thing sounds a bit too bizarre, and the source is certainly partisan. So what did actually happen? Did they confiscate diabetes supplies and tampons while allowing anyone with a concealed carry permit to bring a handgun inside?

Comment: Two more, slightly more respectable sources: [HuffPo](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/07/12/tampons-confiscated-texas_n_3588177.html?ncid=edlinkusaolp00000003) and [Slate](http://www.slate.com/blogs/xx_factor/2013/07/12/tampons_and_pads_not_allowed_in_texas_statehouse_as_senate_debate_on_abortion.html)

Comment: This may have something to do with the fact that liberal protestors wanted to throw tampons and pads at legislators; while legal gun carriers had no plans to shoot any legislators.

Answer (score 24):

Tampons were confiscated from spectators wishing to enter the galley area. (Alexandra Petri. *[Security at Texas legislature confiscated tampons, let guns go](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/compost/wp/2013/07/12/security-at-texas-legislature-confiscated-tampons-let-guns-go/)*, FoxNews.com *[Texas Dems vow to fight abortion bill passed by Republican-led Senate](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2013/07/13/texas-dems-vow-to-fight-abortion-bill-passed-by-republican-led-senate/)*)

Also confiscated were feminine pads, suspected urine, feces, and paint. (*FoxNews.com*)

Also, sugar packets, condoms — "anything that could be thrown at legislators". (The Atlantic Wire. *[Tampons Confiscated, Guns Allowed as Texas Senate Debates Abortion](http://www.theatlanticwire.com/politics/2013/07/tampons-banned-texas-senate-gallery-guns-are-ok/67137/)*)

Guns were allowed for those with concealed carry licenses. (*Petri*) (*[An Entry Reserved for Those With Guns](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/03/09/us/guns-get-a-pass-at-texas-capitol.html?pagewanted=all)*)

Eventually, State Sen. Kirk Watson had the guards stop the confiscations. (*Petri*)

I can't find a reliable source regarding the claim about diabetic supplies.

Comment: In context of the quote, "... and other diabetic supplies" might mean sugar, sugary foods, pop, etc.